# Apply Quarkus to non-maven, non-gradle Java projects

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jvm, quarkus

It's great to be able to use Quarkus on `maven` and `gradle` -based Java/JVM projects but what about projects that are built using other build systems like `sbt` or `bazel` or `buck` or anything else that's not a `maven` or `gradle` -based Java/JVM project.

I did hear about the command-line tool to do this, how far is the progress with this? Is there a way to get a sneak-peak!

Answer (score 0):

For now, we don’t have plans to support other build tools. Supporting Gradle and Maven already has its fair share of challenges.

But contributions are always welcome.